# Harmonization of bebop scale

Tags: harmony, jazz, songwriting, arranging, bebop

When you harmonize a bebop scale, you get a succession of X6 and X° chords with tight voicings, which can be thought of as tiny I and V chord progressions. I've read that musicians with polyphonic instruments use that harmonization to write lines for 4 blowers. How is it done?

UPDATE: 
I have the drop 2 chords on piano kind of down: I know the stuff for guitar so I'm coping on piano but I still don't see how you're supposed to use the 4 V-I generated by the bebop harmonization. In any given key, they give the same V-I four times with different voicings. In C, It's all C6's and G7b9's for example. I understand from good comments that there is something more to this than just the tight voicings. As one commentator wrote: how do I break this up and make it into a specific technique?

Comment: This question might be too broad. Also... what's a 4 blower? A horn section?

Comment: Too broad in what way? I didn't write "a 4 blower" but 4 blowers; I meant 4 trombone, sax or horn players, as you have so rightly guessed.

Comment: @ToddWilcox, I think this is a good, narrow question. There's a specific technique here. I'll try to put together an answer at some point tonight.

Comment: @user45784, it can be done with a drop 2 voicing or just with closed voicings. The final result is that each instrument is essentially walking up/down the bebop scale, just beginning on a different starting tone. I'll see if I can put together a complete response with an example later tonight/tomorrow. It's an *awesome* sound. Great for arranging but also for solo piano. I think of it as a more old-fashioned sound.

Answer (score 4):

These examples aren't particularly hard-core bebop, but they show some voicing methods. Also see if you can find  some George Shearing-style arrangements.

[image]

Comment: Nice diagram +1. Since the question is about arranging for 4 horns, it might be worth mentioning how to break this up for arranging purposes, range considerations, etc.